# how to optimize this iteration (ruby)?

Tags: ruby, json, string, parsing, iteration

I have to iterate over some json strings and this is how it looks like:

```
parsed.each do |a|
 a.each do |b|
   if(b.class == Array)
    b.each do |c|
     c["attributes"].each do |d|
      p d
     end
    end
   end
 end
end
```

Can anybody help me to put this in one or two lines? Thanks in advance!

Christian

Comment: Could you post an example input and output?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is the appropriate site for this type of question.

Comment: Code review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is more appropriate to optimize/improve code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parsed.flatten.each do |c|
  c["attributes"].each { |d| p d }
end
```

[Array#flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten) and [Array#flatten!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten-21) for in-place flattening

Comment: Changed it into:

       parsed.each do |a, b|
        if(b.class == Array)
         b.flatten.each do |c|
          c["attributes"].each { |d| p d }
         end
        end
       end

and it looks good now :)

Answer (score 2):

Edited following Jörg W Mittag's suggestion.

```
p(*parsed.grep(Array).flat_map{|c| c["attributes"]})
```

Comment: Hint: whenever you have `select` and `===`, just use `grep` instead. `grep` uses `===`. So, just do `grep(Array)`.